# $\phi : G → G'$, sends each conjugacy class of $G$ to a corresponding conjugacy class of the same size in $G'$

Tags: group-theory

I came across a problem in my textbook which I am having issues solving.

Show that a group isomorphism, $\phi : G → G'$, sends each conjugacy class of $G$ to a corresponding conjugacy class of the same size in $G'$

Can someone explain how I should approach proving this problem. Any help would be great.

Comment: Which textbook are you referring to?

Comment: What have you tried? You can start by showing that if two elements are conjugate in $G$, then their images are conjugate in $G'$, and similarly if two elements are conjugate in $G'$ then they are conjugate in $G$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a \in G$; its conjugacy class is $\operatorname{Cl}(a)=\{gag^{-1}, g \in G\}$. Therefore:

\begin{alignat}{1}
\phi(\operatorname{Cl}(a)) &= \{\phi(gag^{-1}), g\in G\} \\
&= \{\phi(g)\phi(a)\phi(g^{-1}), g\in G\} \\
&= \{\phi(g)\phi(a)\phi(g)^{-1}, g\in G\} \\
&\stackrel{(*)}{=} \{g'\phi(a)g'^{-1}, g'\in G'\} \\
&= \operatorname{Cl}(\phi(a))
\end{alignat}

where the equality $(*)$ holds because $\phi$ is surjective, and thence as $g$ spans $G$, $g':=\phi(g)$ does span $G'$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\psi:G'\rightarrow G$ the inverse of the isomorphism $\phi:G\rightarrow G'$ and let $X_g$ the conjugacy class of $g$ in $G$ and $Y_h$ the conjugacy class of $h$ in $G'$.

We are going to construct a bijection between $X_g$ and $Y_{\phi(g)}$. For, take the two maps:
\begin{gather}
F:X_g\rightarrow Y_{\phi(g)}\qquad F(xgx^{-1}):=\phi(xgx^{-1}) = \phi(x)\phi(g)\phi(x)^{-1}\\
G:Y_{\phi(g)}\rightarrow X_{g}\qquad G(y\phi(g)y^{-1}):=\psi(y\phi(g)y^{-1}) = \psi(y)g\psi(y)^{-1}
\end{gather}
Thanks to the fact that $\phi,\psi$ are morphism we have that the maps $F$ and $G$ are well defined.

Now it's easy to show that $FG=\text{id}$ and $GF=\text{id}$.

Answer (score 1):

You are showing that the class equation is an invariant.  This is straight forward symbolic manipulation.

It's easy to check an isomorphism preserves centers, conjugacy classes, and non-central conjugacy classes.  It follows that the class equations of isomorphic groups are the same up to re-ordering.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $\textbf{Grp}_*$ being the category of pointed groups. Define a functor
$$(G, g) \mapsto \mathrm{Cl}(G, g) = \{ xgx^{-1} \in G \mid x\in G  \}$$
$$\bigg( (G, g) \xrightarrow{\phi} (H,h)\bigg) \mapsto \bigg( \mathrm{Cl}(G, g) \xrightarrow{\mathrm{Cl}(\phi)} \mathrm{Cl}(H, h)\bigg)$$
where $\mathrm{Cl}(\phi)(x)=\phi(x)$.

Functors preserve isomorphisms.

(I couldn't resist).